# Why does my scope binding to a service array not update when the array gets replaced

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I have a scope binding to an array stored in a service.
When the array changes, the scope notices the change and updates the values in my template.

However, when the Array gets replaced by another array, the scope doesn't seem to recognize a change and won't update the list.

I know that this is a common behaviour of angularjs and that it's probably intended to be like this, but I don't get why.
In my understanding, the scope variable should update, whenever the bound reference changes.

Is `$scope.myVar = anyOtherVar;` not equivalent to a `$scope.$watch('anyOtherVar',function(..){//update myVar});` ?

See my fiddle for demonstrating the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/sL9k7q9L/1/

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
myApp.factory('myService', function() {
    var anyArray = [{"name":"peter"}];

  var anyOtherArray = [{"name":"laura"}];

  return {
    anyArray: anyArray,
    newElement: function(){
        anyArray.push({"name":"bob"});
    },
    replaceWholeArray: function(){
        anyArray = anyOtherArray;
      console.log(anyArray);
    }
  }
});

function MyCtrl($scope,myService) {
    $scope.elements = myService.anyArray;
    $scope.newElement = function(){
        myService.newElement();
    }
    $scope.replaceWholeArray = function(){
        myService.replaceWholeArray();
    }
}
```

and the corresponding template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="newElement()">
    newElement()
  </button>
  <button ng-click="replaceWholeArray()">
    replaceWholeArray()
  </button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="el in elements">{{el.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: All relevant code should be contained in the question itself. questions need to be self contained. Demos are only used to support what is actually in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating variables but that doesn't update any other variable assignments that were made using the original variable.

Thus reference to original array is broken for `myService.anyArray`

Simple example

```
var a = 1;
var b = a;
a = 2;
alert(b);// is still 1 due to value of `a` when it was assigned
```

Instead just update the factory object property but to do that you need to store a reference to the returned object first

```
myApp.factory('myService', function() {
  var anyArray = [...];

  var anyOtherArray = [...];

  var factoryObject = {
    anyArray: anyArray,
    newElement: function() {
      anyArray.push({"name": "bob"});
    },
    replaceWholeArray: function() {
      // change this part
      //anyArray = anyOtherArray;
      // To:
      factoryObject.anyArray = anyOtherArray;
    }
  }

  return factoryObject
});
```

Comment: ok, that makes sense. So in general a `$scope.any = anyOther` binding does not register a watcher for `anyOther` ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with watchers it has to do with breaking reference to original array set in the returned service. See the simple example I added

Comment: the `watcher` was meant in the way of how angularjs handles two-way-bindings, and when it checks for changes for the bound references. But it seems i have to dig a little deeper into that topic

Comment: Issue is a javascript fundamental issue. Angular can't watch a broken reference